Campagnolo Ekar thumb shifter hooks from half of the cassette
I'm new here and hope someone can help me. My Campagnolo Ekar has now completed its first 500 kilometres. Unfortunately the thumb shifter is stuck. From the centre of the cassette, the thumb shifter has to be pulled slightly upwards once per shift (see picture) to feel a pressure point again so that the chain jumps to the next smaller sprocket.
A friend of mine said he had the same problem and that he only needed to tighten one screw on the STI. Unfortunately he can't remember which one.
Does anyone know the problem and have any advice?
Best regards + thanks
Toni


I'm not familiar with these, but 500km from new, the inner cable is likely a little stretched or settled.   It may be a simple tension adjustment on a barrel fitting, somewhere in the cabling or perhaps down on the rear derailleur.   A little light lube in the shifter probably won' hurt either.

I had a similar issue with the Ekar. It was caused by a worn cable, which meant that the derailleur spring couldn't pull the cable back quick enough when shifting to smaller cogs. This resulted in the bead dislodging inside the shifter and getting jammed.
To fix this, I removed the rubber cover and unmounted the shifter from the bars. This gave me access to the rotating shift assembly inside the shifter. I loosened the bolt at its center, removed the clamping plate and re-positioned the cable and bead.
After this, the plate needs to be re-installed. The bolt needs to be tightened to a very specific torque, similar to a bearing preload. If it's too tight or too loose, shifting won't work properly. This takes a lot of try and error.

I suspect that in your case, the cable is actually fine (as it is almost new) and the bead might not be dislodged, but the bolt is too loose. Perhaps you just need to tighten it a very small amount.
When the cable is correctly positioned, the bead is visible through a little window on the shifter when in either the highest or lowest gear (I forgot which one):

If this is the case, you don't need to reposition the cable.
Beware: The whole shifting assembly consists of many tiny parts that are hard to re-assemble correctly. Take photos of the original state. The bolt is difficult to adjust. The clamping bolt for mounting the shifter to the bars is made of very soft metal and easy to damage. The rubber cover is fragile as well. Fiddling with the shifter can also mess with the brake and require bleeding it after. So it might be better to ask a professional as you can easily make it worse.

Thank you so much! THis helped!

Awesome, nice to know!

If the shifter is that new, return to the retailer, or you risk voiding your warranty.
This sounds like a loose centre-bolt in the internal assembly but it can also have other causes.
